# Phone numbers disappear from website on ipad

Tags: php, html, ios, phone-number

I'm finding this a total "WTF" situation. [On this website](http://www.akra.com.au) the phone numbers on the contact page disappear when viewed on ipad and iphone. On everything else, the phone numbers display correctly. There is a phone number on the home page which displays correctly on ipad and iphone, but the numbers on the contact page do not.

I have tried:

- Removing additional form scripts in contact page and/or also in header file. Result: numbers still do not display;
- Using html characters instead of +, ( and ). Result: numbers still do not display;
- Using letters instead of numbers. Result: text displays correctly;
- Copying & pasting phone number from contact page into home page. Result: numbers display correctly on home page
- Copying & pasting phone number from contact page into other pages. Result: numbers do not display;
- Checking for invisible characters. Result: no invisible characters.

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191014/phone-number-are-not-visible-in-ipad) related to this issue, but it has been closed as not a real question.

Please find below my code:

```
    <p><em>A &amp; K Ross Associatest Pty Ltd</em><br>
    3 Gunyah Drive<br>
    Trentham<br>
    Vic 3458 Australia<br>
    Email: info@akra.com.au<br>
    Telephone: + 61 (0)3 5424 1700</p>
    <p><em>Alan Ross</em><br>
    Mobile: +61 (0)407 842 537</p>
    <p><em>Katherine Ross</em><br>
    Mobile: +61 (0)438 120 704</p>
```

Yes, sure, it's probably a ridiculous mistake I've made somewhere, but I can't for the life of me find where I've made it.

I'd really appreciate some assistance. MTIA.

EDIT:

I am not using any styling specific to mobile/handheld devices or screen widths etc. CSS styles applied to text as follows:

```
.contact p {
line-height:18px;
margin-bottom:13px;
}
p {
color:#858585;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
width:630px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615822/ipad-contact-link-css-override

Comment: Bingo. Yep. I had the following `a:link {color: #fff;}` which was overriding other styling. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phone numbers get a different style on iPad and iPhone, so that you can tap them to call. I might guess that you have a conflicting styling in your CSS that uses their class, making it white or invisible.

Comment: Thanks, but as per my edit in my post above, I am not using any specific styling.

Comment: If you take ALL styling off the whole page, do you get the same issue?

Comment: This *is* actually the problem I was having. My stylesheet reset used `a:link {color:#fff;}` which the ipad and iphone used. Interestingly, android did not use the color styling despite also adding a href link to the phone numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked out a simple solution. Iphone cretaes anchor tag for the phone no and apply white color so it becomes invisible.

Normal view on browsers

```
         <span class="Phone-no">1800-658-128</span>
```

Iphone View

```
         <span class="Phone-no"><a>1800-658-128</a></span>
```

Solution

```
.Phone-no a{
   color : #0000;
  }
```

Change the color to user desired one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, I am having the same trouble with iPhone! Knowing about the invisible added `<a>` helps sort that out, except for the spacing issues created by the tag! So much extra work just for iPhone!!! So I made this style:

```
.iphoneSucksForMakingMeStyleThisText a {color: black;}
```

to go with this HTML in a modal:

```
  <div class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
    <h3>SOLD</h3>
    <p class="iphoneSucksForMakingMeStyleThisText">Call: 0000000000</p>
    <p>Email: bla@blablabla.co.za</p>
  </div>
```